# sigining iphone app with customer certificate and provisioning profile

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

I went through all related questions here on the site as well blogs but they leave it open that I can re-use the certificates and profiles of customers. There is no problem of course when the distribution and certificate has been generated with the CSR of my server.

I need to build iphone apps on a dedicated server, using the uploaded p12 certificates and mobile provision profiles of customers.

I am facing 2 scenarios :

1. Distribution for AppStore submissions
2. Ad-hoc

Regarding 1.) I could import and sign the app as follows :

1. security import CertificatesVOSX.p12 -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain -P "asdasd" -T /usr/bin/codesign
2. xcrun -verbose -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication "build/Release-iphoneos/JIOSApp.app" -o /tmp/app.ipa -sign "iPhone Distribution: PUBLISHING LIMITED" -embed JIOSBase.mobileprovision

This went fine but of course iTunes fails to install it. Does this application works for Appstore submissions ?

Then regarding 2.)

As said, usually the customer has their own certs, bound to the original CSR. xcodebuild or xcrun doesn't work here, because of a private key mismatch.

Did anybody could build apps with customer's certs and mobile provision profiles yet ? Seems rather impossible to me.

Thanks,
Guenter

Reference Links :

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tools-utilities/73719-hudson-continuous-integration-ios.html

[Name of Provisioning Profile used to sign an iPhone app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327257/name-of-provisioning-profile-used-to-sign-an-iphone-app)

And the most related one but still not 100% answered : [Command line installation of Code Signing certificates, .p12 files, and mobileprovisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357744/command-line-installation-of-code-signing-certificates-p12-files-and-mobilepr)